# How to configure docker registry to make a priority to local registry when PULL?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm new to docker, then the problem may describe not clearly in title. I want to do it that when I use pull image, it will check local registry at first. Then, if there is no this image in local registry, it will download from docker hub and auto push it to local registry. How to do it?

 `docker hub <-> registry <-> client pull image`

Comment: You can't.  The docker folks want to make sure that if someone types `docker pull foo` they are getting the same image as anybody else running the same command.  If you were able to configure Docker to refer preferentially to a local registry this would no longer be the case, and could lead to confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can use [Mirror](http://docs.docker.com/articles/registry_mirror/) to do this work:

> it pulls the image from the public Docker registry and stores it
>   locally before handing it back to you. On subsequent requests, the
>   local registry mirror is able to serve the image from its own storage.